# Get the inner text of child node and stored it in a string separated by delimiter

Tags: sql, xml

I want to get the inner text of the child nodes with comma separator using xsl.

we cant specify the child node element in code.. it may be whatever.

example:

> <aff
>   id="affa"><org><orgname><nameelt>Department of
>   Applied Chemistry</nameelt><nameelt>Graduate School of
>   Urban Environmental Sciences, Tokyo Metropolitan
>   University</nameelt></orgname></org><address><addrelt>Minamiohsawa,
>   Hachioji</addrelt><city>Tokyo
>   192-0397</city><country>Japan</country></address><email>hulie@au.ac.jp</email></aff>

my code is,

```
SELECT 
REPLACE(Element.value('(.)[1]','NVARCHAR(MAX)'), CHAR(10), '') AS address
FROM    @xml.nodes('aff') Datalist ( Element );
```

Expected output:

> Department of Applied Chemistry, Graduate School of Urban
>   Environmental Sciences, Tokyo Metropolitan University, Minamiohsawa,
>   Hachioji, Tokyo 192-0397 ... like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<aff id="affa">
  <org>
    <orgname>
      <nameelt>Department of Applied Chemistry</nameelt>
      <nameelt>Graduate School of Urban Environmental Sciences, Tokyo Metropolitan University</nameelt>
    </orgname>
  </org>
  <address>
    <addrelt>Minamiohsawa, Hachioji</addrelt>
    <city>Tokyo 192-0397</city>
    <country>Japan</country>
  </address>
  <email>hulie@au.ac.jp</email>
</aff>';
```

--The query uses `.nodes()` to get all `<nameelt>`-elements. By using `FOR XML PATH('')` the results are returned as one long, comma separated string and `STUFF` will cut off the leading comma finally:

```
SELECT STUFF(
(
    SELECT ', ' + n.value(N'text()[1]','nvarchar(max)')
    FROM @xml.nodes(N'/aff/org/orgname/nameelt') AS A(n)
    FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
).value(N'text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'),1,2,'');
```